# C# Comparing data with database by using array

Tags: c#

My database contains 2 records. So, I retrieve these 2 records and store in array. Let's say my database have `start point`, `destination`, `terminal` and `departure time`. If user trying to add `same start` point, same `destination`, same `terminal` and same `departure time`, it will show error message. But if user trying to add same `start point`, same `destination`, same `terminal` but DIFFERENT `departure time`. It  suppose to allow user add, but I having problem with user not allow to add.

Example:

These record are in my database

```
Record 1 : Terminal = 1 , From = US , To = UK,   Time = 10.00  
Record 2 : Terminal = 1 , From = US , To = AUS , Time = 2.00
```

When user want to add new record

User wish to add: `Terminal = 1, From = US, To = AUS, Time = 10.00`

It's tell me record exist because the time 10.00 exist in other record which is in different destination. Anyone can help?

```
if (ow_terminal.Any(s => ddlterminal.SelectedValue.Contains(s)) 
 && ow_depart.Any(s => ddlDeparture.SelectedValue.Contains(s)) 
 && ow_origin.Any(s => ddlOrigin.SelectedValue.Contains(s)) 
 && ow_destination.Any(s => ddlDestination.SelectedValue.Contains(s)))
{
    lblMessage.Text = "Record exist";  
}
else
{ 
    lblMessage.Text = "No record exist"
}
```

Comment: What about sharing some code?

Comment: You'd have to post more information if you want help. Does the problem occur in the C# program, or in the database. If it's in the database then the table specification would be necessary.

Comment: The problem is in C# program. because when I going to add the exactly same record as record 2 ( shown in above ) but different time(Example :10.00),its show me record exist because the time (10.00) exist in record 1. It suppose to show no record exist because the destination ( AUS) is not same.

Comment: That last code block isn't really explained. Is that what's telling you the record already exists? Or is that an attempt to resolve the issue? If the latter, what does any of this have to do with a database? It looks like it's all in C#. Furthermore, it seems kind of weird to be storing all those values separately. Is there a reason you took that approach?

Comment: Sir, I am comparing those data that user enter with database, if only all of the 4 entered data are same as database record, record exist message will prompt, if anyone of these 4 data are different from database record, no record exist message should be prompt

Comment: Your comparisons are flawed. Don't use 'Contains' when you want to check for equality - otherwise `US` will match `AUS`, `1.00` will match `11.00` etc. Also, why are you checking this in code? Get your database to do the search, set a unique key across these fields.

Comment: Yes, my database contain routeID, but before user add new route into database, I want to compare is the route exist or not.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with your Linq statement.

Think logically about what it is actually saying:

```
if(terminal_array.Any(s => new_terminal_record.Contains(s)))
```

So if ANY of the values in your terminal_array matches the new terminal record that the user entered then this statement is true, and your code will then evaluate the next line

```
if(depart_array.Any(s => new_depart_record.Contains(s)))
```

And it will do the same thing, if ANY of the values in your depart array matches the new departure record that the user entered then this statement is also true.

What you most likely want to do is to store the records in an array of whatever your record type is and do the Linq statement over each record in that array, something along the lines of:

```
if(records_array.Any(s => new_record.terminal.Equals(s.terminal) &&
                          new_record.depart.Equals(s.depart) &&
                          new_record.origin.Equals(s.origin) &&
                          new_record.destination.Equals(s.destination)))
{
     // Record Exists
}
else
{
     // No Record Exists
}
```

For a more complete example, I have replicated **your** implementation and then included *my* implementation:

```
class Program
{
    // Example of database records
    struct _dbTypes
    {
        public string terminal;
        public string depart;
        public string origin;
        public string destination;
    };

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // First record
        _dbTypes record1;
        record1.terminal = "1";
        record1.depart = "10.00";
        record1.origin = "US";
        record1.destination = "UK";

        // Second record
        _dbTypes record2;
        record2.terminal = "1";
        record2.depart = "2.00";
        record2.origin = "US";
        record2.destination = "AUS";

        // Your implementation has each of the records internals
        // separated into their own array
        List<String> terminals = new List<string>();
        List<String> departs = new List<string>();
        List<String> origins = new List<string>();
        List<String> destination = new List<string>();

        terminals.Add(record1.terminal);
        terminals.Add(record2.terminal);
        departs.Add(record1.depart);
        departs.Add(record2.depart);
        origins.Add(record1.origin);
        origins.Add(record2.origin);
        destination.Add(record1.destination);
        destination.Add(record2.destination);

        // The NEW record that the user has entered
        _dbTypes record3;
        record3.terminal = "1";
        record3.depart = "10.00";
        record3.origin = "US";
        record3.destination = "AUS";

        // Example of your implementation
        if (terminals.Any(s => record3.terminal.Contains(s)) &&
           departs.Any(s => record3.depart.Contains(s)) &&
           origins.Any(s => record3.origin.Contains(s)) &&
           destination.Any(s => record3.destination.Contains(s)))
        {
            // Will fall into here
            Console.WriteLine("Record exists");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("No record exists");
        }

        // What you should probably be doing...
        //
        // Array of your record type
        List<_dbTypes> dataBaseEntries = new List<_dbTypes>();
        //
        // Add the first two records as a whole record, not separated out
        dataBaseEntries.Add(record1);
        dataBaseEntries.Add(record2);

        // Now you want to do the Linq statement over the record
        // AND'ing each .Equals on the current records internal objects
        if (dataBaseEntries.Any(s => record3.terminal.Equals(s.terminal) &&
                                    record3.depart.Equals(s.depart) &&
                                    record3.origin.Equals(s.origin) &&
                                    record3.destination.Equals(s.destination)))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Record exists");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("No record exists");
            dataBaseEntries.Add(record3);
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I can tell, you seem to be storing the information for each record in separate arrays, one each for terminal, depart, origin, and destination. This is a bit problematic since there isn't a concrete way of determining that the information belongs to the same record UNLESS for some reason, the information are ordered in the array per record:

example:

```
ow_terminal[0] = 1
ow_depart[0] = "US"
ow_origin[0] = "UK"
ow_destination[0] = 10.00
```

If this is the case, then you have to change your if statement logic. I don't think LINQ can help in this case, but you can try:

```
bool exists = false;

for(int i = 0; i < ow_terminal.Count; i++)
{
    if(ddlterminal.SelectedValue.Contains(ow_terminal[i])
       && ddlDeparture.SelectedValue.Contains(ow_depart[i])
       && ddlOrigin.SelectedValue.Contains(ow_origin[i])
       && ddlDestination.SelectedValue.Contains(ow_destination[i]))
     {
           exists = true;
           break;
     }
}

if(exists) lblMessage.Text = "Record exist"; 
else lblMessage.Text = "No record exist";
```

The code checks the values of each array in the same position for equality. Again, this would only work if the items on all of the arrays are arranged per record. ALSO, you may want to change the equality check since `Contains` may not be best fit for your purpose ("US" is *contained* in "RUSSIA", for example.)

HOWEVER, managing four arrays and making sure that they are ordered correctly all the time is very fragile. What you want to do is to create just one array (or list) of objects that correspond to your record with corresponding properties:

```
public class FlightRecord
{
    public int Terminal {get;set;}
    public string From {get;set;}
    public string To {get;set;}
    public decimal Time {get;set;} // How are you storing time?
}
```

Create an array of FlightRecords from your database records and then you can do your logic like you wanted with a few minor changes:

```
if (ow_flightrecords.Any(s => ddlterminal.SelectedValue.Contains(s.Terminal.ToString() 
    && ddlDeparture.SelectedValue.Contains(s.Time.ToString())
    && ddlOrigin.SelectedValue.Contains(s.From)
    && ddlDestination.SelectedValue.Contains(s.To)))
{
    lblMessage.Text = "Record exist";  
}
else
{ 
    lblMessage.Text = "No record exist"
}
```

This one is more robust and you can use LINQ easily. Again, change how you do the comparisons since `Contains` may not be as good a fit for your purpose as you think it is.

And as Synchro noted, it's probably a good idea to do the check on the database directly via a stored procedure before you do the actual INSERT into the database. It will be much faster this way.